# Should questions about the user experience of the site itself be on meta or the main site?

Tags: discussion, meta

Should questions about the user experience of the UX Stack Exchange site itself be on meta or the main site?

- Questions about the site itself should be on meta
- Questions about user experience are on-topic for UX Stack Exchange

I've come across some questions about the site itself that were asked on the main site: [Why are vote buttons on Stack Exchange shown when they can't be used?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/53986/why-are-vote-buttons-on-stack-exchange-shown-when-they-cant-be-used)

And some others that were asked on meta.

Are these types of questions on-topic for both the main site and meta? What is preferred?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Questions about the UX of the site are primarily opinion based questions, in the same way that questions about the UX amazon.com are.  Hence it would not be allowed on the main site.  It would however be appropriate to ask them on meta.ux.stackexchange.com.

The mods have little (if any) control over the UX of the site, as that is set by StackExchange, not us.